# NAT with iptables: need help understanding

Tags: iptables, nat, pat, dnat

i am trying to learn NAT with iptables but i ran into some confusions.

i am having two virtual machines with ips 18.43 lets say **B** and 18.42 **C** running webservers on port 80.
i need to NAT every traffic coming on **B:80** to **C:80** (Do not want to use any other techinique other than NAT)

rule on B with **ip-forward** on and Default Policy of every chain is to ACCEPT

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.10.18.43 --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to 10.10.18.42:80
```

When i make request from A(my machine **11.46**) to B:80 i can see the following on tcpdump 
of Machine B

```
12:24:43.488944 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.43.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554127 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
12:24:43.488986 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554127 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
12:24:44.488106 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.43.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554377 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
12:24:44.488138 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554377 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
12:24:46.492250 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.43.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554878 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
12:24:46.492283 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554878 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
```

Also on the Machine C i am getting following on tcpdump

```
 12:24:43.497050 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554127 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
 12:24:43.497116 IP 10.10.18.42.http > 10.10.11.46.43149: Flags [S.], seq 450030769, ack 3856561848, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2097931 ecr 2554127,nop,wscale 7], length 0
 12:24:44.496174 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554377 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
 12:24:44.496227 IP 10.10.18.42.http > 10.10.11.46.43149: Flags [S.], seq 450030769, ack 3856561848, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2098181 ecr 2554127,nop,wscale 7], length 0
 12:24:44.970715 IP 10.10.18.42.http > 10.10.11.46.43149: Flags [S.], seq 450030769, ack 3856561848, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2098300 ecr 2554127,nop,wscale 7], length 0.
 12:24:46.500288 IP 10.10.11.46.43149 > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [S], seq 3856561847, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554878 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
 12:24:46.500336 IP 10.10.18.42.http > 10.10.11.46.43149: Flags [S.], seq 450030769, ack 3856561848, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2098682 ecr 2554127,nop,wscale 7], length 0
 12:24:46.970717 IP 10.10.18.42.http > 10.10.11.46.43149: Flags [S.], seq 450030769, ack 3856561848, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2098800 ecr 2554127,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

But i am not getting any Reply back to Machine A.,If my interpretation is correct on machine C packets are coming as source ip 11.46(A) and 18.42(C) is replying to A but why are the packets not reaching A.Do i need more rules on B to make this work.

**Update**

added SNAT

```
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             to:10.10.18.43:80
```

Tcpdump on machine B:

```
   15:13:38.816289 IP 10.10.11.46.44423 > 10.10.18.43.http: Flags [P.], seq 2436344770:2436345215, ack 4133534960, win 892, options [nop,nop,TS val 5087771 ecr 4627759], length 445
15:13:38.816332 IP 10.10.18.43.http > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [P.], seq 2436344770:2436345215, ack 4133534960, win 892, options [nop,nop,TS val 5087771 ecr 4627759], length 445
15:13:38.817173 IP 10.10.18.42.http > 10.10.18.43.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:159, ack 445, win 231, options [nop,nop,TS val 4631763 ecr 5087771], length 158
15:13:38.817206 IP 10.10.18.43.http > 10.10.11.46.44423: Flags [P.], seq 1:159, ack 445, win 231, options [nop,nop,TS val 4631763 ecr 5087771], length 158
15:13:38.818819 IP 10.10.11.46.44423 > 10.10.18.43.http: Flags [.], ack 159, win 926, options [nop,nop,TS val 5087772 ecr 4631763], length 0
15:13:38.818830 IP 10.10.18.43.http > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [.], ack 159, win 926, options [nop,nop,TS val 5087772 ecr 4631763], length 0
```

tcpdump on machine C:

```
15:13:38.824622 IP 10.10.18.43.http > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [P.], seq 2436344770:2436345215, ack 4133534960, win 892, options [nop,nop,TS val 5087771 ecr 4627759], length 445
15:13:38.824880 IP 10.10.18.42.http > 10.10.18.43.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:159, ack 445, win 231, options [nop,nop,TS val 4631763 ecr 5087771], length 158
15:13:38.826811 IP 10.10.18.43.http > 10.10.18.42.http: Flags [.], ack 159, win 926, options [nop,nop,TS val 5087772 ecr 4631763], length 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.10.18.43 --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to 10.10.18.42:80

As [khaled](https://serverfault.com/users/58024/khaled) specified machine **A** was confused with reply from **C** and Rejected all the packets from C.

SNAT ing source ip fixed this

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.10.18.43

Answer (score -1):

You did not tell us exactly how these machines are connected and whether they are attached to a single subnet or not. However, I can assume at least that machines B and C are in the same subnet and machine A is in different one.

Your setup will not work this way. You will not receive any response back to your machine A because the server C is replying back directly to machine A and not through NATing box (server B in this case).

Machine A will get confused as it is sending to machine B and receiving response back from machine C.

In order to make it work, you need to do the NATing on the gateway of machines B and C.

Comment: Unfortunatley i dont know  much about the vm connectivity i only have permission to launch new vm.I am able to connect to that vm from my network 11.0/ and on the vm i can see 18.1 as their Gateway.Also since vm are on same subnet it can ping each other.Can you please tell me why Nating will not work in this case.it can be of very Help.

Comment: @KevinParker: My answer should explain this!