# Proxmox Nat Networking Issue

Tags: iptables, nat, proxmox, masquerade, dnat

## Definition

I have installed Proxmox 3.2 and i am trying to configure a virtual machine as a communication server that handles all traffic and forwards them to the nodes with private ip.

I configured server for NAT networking with two CentOS virtual machines which has exactly same configuration.

## What I Do

[Proxmox](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Model#Masquerading_.28NAT.29) wiki has a very limited and basic nat networking documentation.
I found similar problems ([this](https://serverfault.com/questions/532938/proxmox-single-public-ip-with-multiple-vms-openvz-containers-work-kvms-don), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/470969/nat-with-iptables-need-help-understanding)) on here  and on proxmox forums. I tried to understand basics of [linux nat networking](http://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial) so I complete this very understandable tutorial from beginning to end. I read this article for [iptables nat rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html)

## Problems

After installation and configuration when I ping from host to VM or from VM to host the output is:

```
root@testPrx:~# ping 10.0.4.2
PING 10.0.4.2 (10.0.4.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.4.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

When I try a telnet connection to communication server's public ip from a server in the same network which has internet connection and (192.168.0.3)

```
bash-4.1# telnet 192.168.0.2 2701
Trying 192.168.0.2...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.2: No route to host
```

When I try telnet connection to localhost, 192.168.0.2 results same:

```
root@testPrx:~# telnet localhost 2701
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

## Question

What is my mistake?

## Configurations

All host and virtual machines configurations are:

### Proxmox Server

#### Proxmox version

```
root@testPrx:~# pveversion
pve-manager/3.2-4/e24a91c1 (running kernel: 2.6.32-29-pve)
```

#### Network interfaces

Network interfaces added by web interface:
[image]

- net0 -> vmbr0
- net1 -> vmbr1

  `root@testPrx:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces`

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto vmbr0
  iface vmbr0 inet static
          address 192.168.0.2
          netmask 255.255.255.0
          gateway 192.168.0.1
          bridge_ports eth0
          bridge_stp off
          bridge_fd 0
  auto vmbr1
  iface vmbr1 inet static
          address 10.0.4.1
          netmask 255.255.255.0
          bridge_ports none
          bridge_stp off
          bridge_fd 0

  post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.4.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
  post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.4.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE

  #these rules forward traffic on port 2701 to port 22 on the VM at IP 10.0.4.2

  post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 2701 -j DNAT --to 10.0.4.2:22
  post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 2702 -j DNAT --to 10.0.4.2:22
  ```

#### Firewall rules of nat ( there is no any filters)

```
root@testPrx:~# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2701 to:10.0.4.2:22

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.4.0/24          anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

#### Routing table

```
root@testPrx:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.4.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
```

Ip forwarding

```
root@testPrx:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

### Virtual Machines

#### OS version

```
-bash-4.1# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

#### Interfaces

**eth0**

```
-bash-4.1# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.0.3
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

**eth1**

```
-bash-4.1# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.0.4.2
GATEWAY=10.0.4.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

**SSH daemon running and listening port(22) succesfully**

```
-bash-4.1# netstat -puntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:85                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1100/sshd
```

#### Routing Table

```
-bash-4.1# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.4.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
default         10.0.4.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake when i was sleeping, so i woke up immediately and fixed this. The interface which is doing nat networking is vmbr1 but when i setup virtual machine i was assigning wrong bridge mode (vmbr0) to network device.

To fix this i stopped virtual machine and edited bridge mode from vmbr0 to vmbr1. Now everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: The same thing here, solving things while on the sleep is the only and the right way! :D